# Is it possible to design $\text{DFA}\{x,y\}$ that has at least $2$ $x$'s and at most $2$ $y$'s?

Tags: automata

$L = \{w|$, $w$ has at least $2 x$'s and at most $2 y$'s}

I tried making one but it does not accept aab nor aabb.

If it's possible to draw one, how do you do it?
plus is it possible to draw NFA?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBlm1.png)

Comment: Your DFA fails because it dosen't "remember" how many $y$'s it received.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here each time a $y$ is received, we move down 1 row until we reach $q_9$ (the trash).

Each time an $x$ is received, we move across 1 column until the accepting states.

(Plus it is always possible to draw an NFA first, then convert to DFA.)

Comment: Thank you! Could you also teach me how to draw NFA for this?

Comment: A DFA is an NFA, so I don't know what an NFA for this would be. (And also I haven't drew an NFA in 2 years)